# How to pass parameter through url using jquery ajax without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to pass parameter using Get method in Asp.Net. But in address bar url did not change.

Please any one help me to pass parameter using ajax call through url.

Some try from my side is as below Consider url as below

```
        var obj = { templateName: templateName, pageIndex: pageIndex };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "result.aspx/DisplayResult",
            // data: "{'templateName':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + " &pageIndex : '" + pageIndex + "'' }",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result.value);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You don't need to apply `JSON.stringify()` on `obj`. Should be just: `data: obj,...`

Comment: What is wrong with passing data the way it is mentioned in the question?? If you want url to change you can do it through javascript code and still pass data as you have done.If you want to pass data through url only you should use POST method instead of GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX request looks fine, but there's no reason it'd change the URL. If your request is successful, it will be handled by the `OnSuccess` function. However, I don't see where you've defined the function referenced by `onSuccess`. Try this:

```
   var obj = { templateName: templateName, pageIndex: pageIndex };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "result.aspx/DisplayResult",
            // data: "{'templateName':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + " &pageIndex : '" + pageIndex + "'' }",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
              // You should see the response object in your dev console
              console.log(response);
              // If you want to manipulate the URL for some reason after a successful callback,
              // do that here, or better, call a function referenced elsewhere that does it.
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result.value);
            }
        });
```

Comment: But In url I did not found variables passed through parameters.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Do you mean that after your GET request returns from the server, the URL in your browser has not changed?

Comment: Yes, I have to change url in browser when page change or back button click without refreshing page.